# Client-side Validation in Struts 2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, client-side-validation

I am new at Java Web. I follow a tutorial about struts 2 at: [http://viralpatel.net](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/12/struts2-validation-framework-tutorial-example.html)

I success at create server-side validation, but the client-side do not work. When submit, I notice that a javascript method is not defined. Try viewing source, I see no script is generated. 
This is generated HTML source

```
http://pastebin.com/Lc49jnMs
```

There is no javascript 'validateForm_customer()' method.

In customer.jsp, I have added validate attrubute:

```
<s:form action="customer.action" method="post" theme="xhtml" validate="true">
```

and also added:

```
 <s:actionerror/>
 <s:fielderror />
```

and

```
 <s:head/>
```

In struts.xml:

```
<action name="customer" class="mypackage.CustomerAction">
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/customer.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In code, i have extended ActionSupport, and I have CustomerAction-validation.xml file.
Only client-side validation do not work, the server-side validation do work perfectly.

I am using struts 2.1.6. I don't know but the newer vesion also do not work with me. It build success but have some error in dispatcher initialize, so when using taglib "struts-tags", it throw an error

```
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

caused by

```
org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
```

class not found!

The struts 2.1.6 seems work good until i try using validation.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Hi @binhnx218 , This is Viral. I'm glad my site has been helpful to you. Regarding your problem: Can you post your struts.xml code. It would be helpful to find the cause of problem.

Comment: Hi @viralpatel: Your site is a great tutorial site I've ever seen. This is [link to](http://pastebin.com/34LY4G8S) my struts.xml. Thank u so much

Comment: when you using the client side validation,check if it including `validation.js` as if i remember correctly this js file is the key>regarding the exception show the URL which you are hitting when getting this error

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: the request include 2 js file: utils.js and validation.js. But no method name formValidation_customer() in both 2 file.

Comment: There's nothing missing that I can see here in your example. As you mentioned utils.js and validation.js are already getting included in your HTML doc. Thus struts is properly including req lib.

Comment: @viralpatel: Do struts automatically generated javascript code for validation base on my [ActionClass]-validation.xml or only give me a method name, and I must write that method myself? Thank you so much (because your comment and your site too, I learnt a lot from it :D)

Comment: @binhnx218 - Struts automatically generates the javascript validation code for your project. But in this case it is completely ignoring this part though!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I strongly recommend you to use the latest version (for obvious security reasons,), which currently is [2.3.1.1](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.1/index.html)

Then remove struts2-gxp-plugin (it looks like you don't need it), after Then see what happens

Comment: Thanks! My mistake is that I do not notice the server cached the libraries, so they still be built although I've removed from my project. I removed 2 packages antlr-2.7.2, struts2-gxp-plugin, clean and rebuild and then I can run struts 2.3.1.1. But the client-side-validation problem is not solved. Is struts automatically generate javascript for validating base on our [ActionClass]-validation.xml, or we must do it ourself?

Answer (score 1):

After a long trial i figured out that the validation doesn't works on welcome page set in the web.xml file, so some redirect must be carried out inside welcome page and redirect it internally to next page. And this redirect is not noticed by the user. Below is a sample code of my workings.

index.jsp

```
<!--importing jslt library to redirect the page (jar required jstl.jar and standard.jar)  -->
<%@ taglib prefix="j"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

```
<!--redirection the index page to some action named index see strut.xml file  -->
<j:set var="baseUrl" scope="session" value="http://127.0.0.1:8080/strutsBasic/"/>
<j:redirect url="index" />
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
    value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <!-- at this point redirect is mapped to login page -->
    <action name="index">
    <result>/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="login" 
        class="com.pkg.action.LoginAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success">/regform.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

<action name="register" 
        class="com.pkg.action.LoginAction" method="register">
        <result name="success1">success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">regform.jsp</result>
    </action>   

</package>
```

and the rest of the code and validation are same as of @Viral Patel

Answer (score 0):

**Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter** It seems you missed filter mappings in web.xml for the tags you defined. Make sure they are there.

Comment: That is also possible if OP will hit the direct jsp page containing the stuts2 tags

Comment: @thinksteep: It is not the problem. I have mapping-filter in web.xml: [here](http://pastebin.com/nP5THXFe)

Comment: I agree. But it seems OP didn't do that.